# Applying a class to a table cell based on content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple web page that I use as my magic mirror setup (since I couldn't install the actual package on my version of Raspberry Pi.)

On the page, I made a calendar using `table` and manually assign one of two classes to the `td` of each day of the month.

I would like to replace the class of the `td` for the current date. 
I am still very new to Javascript, but from what I've read, it seems like I should be able to:

- get the content of the element, which would be a 1 or 2 digit number.
- compare to current date
- apply a class if it matches

I've tried to do this by copy/pasting and tweaking bits of code... with predictable results. 
Also, I am using moment.js for a couple other date/time elements on the page, in case that changes anything.
I realize there are more elegant calendar solutions out there, but I don't mind updating the HTML by hand every month, since I have to apply the classes to each day.

Any help or constructive criticism is very appreciated.

Here's the relevant code I have so far.

```
<div id="calendar">
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th colspan="7">May</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- WEEK 1 -->
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="M">1</td>
        <td class="D">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- WEEK 2 -->
        <td class="D">3</td>
        <td class="D">4</td>
        <td class="D">5</td>
        <td class="M">6</td>
        <td class="M">7</td>
        <td class="M">8</td>
        <td class="M">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">Etc.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and

```
html, body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
#calendar {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#calendar table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 300px;
}
#calendar th {
    border: white solid 0.75px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
#calendar td {
    border: white solid 0.75px;
    padding: 9px 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.D {
    background-color: #6cfa25;
}
.M {
    background-color: #ff594a;
}
```

Comment: You should try googling exactly your task bullet points, and try something. I don't see any JS code. If you get stuck feel free to ask for help. All that you have written in that bullet points can be found here on SO, and yes, you can make it work as you imagine it.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figured and I am working on it now. Here's the chunk I am working with now     function changeDateStyle(){
 var caldate = document.getElementById("calendar").innerText;
 var today = new Date().getDate();
 if (caldate == getDate) {
   caldate.classList.toggle("active");
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you are doing some research in right direction from your comment and I am about to do similar thing on my application. Also  it took me a while to do it so I am gonna share my solution.

1. You haven't close your `html, body {` tag in CSS
2. You need add one class to all days to be able fetch it
3. You need [to read here](https://clubmate.fi/javascript-adding-and-removing-class-names-from-elements/) about adding classes without overriding existent
4. You need [to read  here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) how to **make changes of all elements**

You where on right track of getting the day of the month and extract calendar day value with `.innerText`.

```js
var today = new Date().getDate();
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("day");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
if (elements[i].innerText==today){
    elements[i].className += ' active';}
}
```

```css
 
html, body {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}    
.active {
background-color: black !important;
color: white !important;
}   
#calendar {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#calendar table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 300px;
}
#calendar th {
    border: white solid 0.75px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
#calendar td {
    border: white solid 0.75px;
    padding: 9px 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.D {
    background-color: #6cfa25;
}
.M {
    background-color: #ff594a;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar">
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th colspan="7">May</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- WEEK 1 -->
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="M day">1</td>
        <td class="D day">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- WEEK 2 -->
        <td class="D day">3</td>
        <td class="D day">4</td>
        <td class="D day">5</td>
        <td class="M day">6</td>
        <td class="M day">7</td>
        <td class="M day">8</td>
        <td class="M day">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">Etc.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great. And I see it working when running the code snippet, but it does not add the class when trying it on my own otherwise empty page, or even in codepen, etc. 
I feel silly for even asking, since it seems like an obvious fix... but any insight into why that could be? Thank you again, feels like I'm close to what I was looking for.

Comment: @user3568395 Not relay without seeing your other codes.  Make all changes I did, close your HTML body tag in CSS, add active class I added and insert JS in right way. Check your dev tools for possible confilcts. Otherwise it should work like in my example.

Comment: Thank you. I got it working by including the javascript in the HTML file. 
There must be something I am doing wrong with my external JS file... but I'll figure that one out on my own.

Comment: @user3568395 try to wrap  my code into a function and load it on window load for example. Other then that id appreciate if you'd mark my answer as accepted so I can get my points for effort  and to mark it as solved. ;)